# cannot load custom tooltips in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, line, tooltip, series

I have created a custoom tooltip for a lineseries chart. however my problem is that this custom tooltip is never loaded..(I still get the default tooltip i.e. X-value)

Is there something I should be doing differently??

page.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="ttip" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedIndependentValue}"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>





<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart" Grid.Row="0">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries
            DataPointStyle="{StaticResource ttip}" />
```

page.xaml.cs (creating and binding)

...

```
             lineSeries = new LineSeries()
            {
                ItemsSource = storageInfo,
                DependentValueBinding = new Binding(dependentValueString),
                IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("CollectionDatek__BackingField"),
            };
        }
```

...

Thanks for your help...

Ron..

Comment: Consider editing the title to be more clear that this relates to Silverlight Toolkit's charting vs. Silverlight in general...

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, you've set the Opacity of the Grid in the template to 0. That means invisible - nothing to see! Either remove the attribute, set it to 1, or consider using some sort of Storyboard to fade it in properly.

David Anson's blog post on ["4 simple color/ToolTip"](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/05/19/chart-tweaking-made-easy-how-to-make-four-simple-color-tooltip-changes-with-silverlight-wpf-charting.aspx) changes should assist you. As your code looks similar, you may already have this reference, but it's a great, concise document for others that find this topic.